# How can make adaptive chain payment using PayPal-Android-SDK

Tags: android, paypal

I am using https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK and able to perform normal paypal payment using PayPal-Client-Metadata-Id and Authorization code.
However as per my requirement, i need to use adaptive chain payment using PayPal-Client-Metadata-Id and Authorization code but unable to find any way to make it possible.